# Как освободить память, занятую std::thread после его завершения?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Есть объект `std::thread`, создающийся внутри функции. Создается так:

```
std::thread* th = new std::thread([](){код лямбды});
```

Однако указатель на объект пропадает после выхода из зоны видимости функции.

Вопрос, как освободить память, занятую `std::thread`, после его завершения?

***P. S.:*** если заменить лямбду на пустую, программа падает уже на строке `th->detach()`.

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7090623/2553424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобное [уже обсуждалось](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52590) в системе отслеживания ошибок GCC. Как оказалось, это связано с тем, что *libpthread* не рассчитана на статическую компоновку:

> При `$ g++-4.7 -Wl,-M -v -static -pthread -std=c++0x -o thread thread.cc` libpthread компонуется без проблем.
>
> Проведя небольшое расследование, я выяснил, что `/usr/include/c++/4.7.0/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-posix.h` объявляет всё как `__attribute__((weakref))` даже при статической компоновке, из-за чего все символы `__gthread_*` обращаются в нулевые. Дополнительная информация может быть найдена по ссылке http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2005-10/msg00235.html
>
> Следующие флаги компиляции должны помочь:
>
> ```
> $ g++ -D_GLIBCXX_GTHREAD_USE_WEAK=0 -static -pthread -std=c++0x -o thread thread.cc 
> $ ./thread 
> pthread_create works
> std::thread works
> ```
>
> Однако, если заменить `join()` на `detach()`, программа снова падает, на этот раз из-за нулевой ссылки на `std::thread::detach`:
>
> ```
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
> (gdb) bt
> #0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
> #1  0x0000000000439785 in std::thread::detach() ()
> #2  0x0000000000401f52 in main ()
> ```
>
> ---
>
> *`$ g++-4.7 -Wl,-M -v -static -pthread -std=c++0x -o thread thread.cc` shows all of libpthread being linked.*
>
> With a bit more digging I traced the problem to `/usr/include/c++/4.7.0/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-posix.h` declaring all of its symbols with `__attribute__((weakref))` even when linking statically. Which caused the `__gthread_*` symbols to resolve to zero. I found this for some background info http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2005-10/msg00235.html
>
> This change made my example work:
>
> ```
> $ g++ -D_GLIBCXX_GTHREAD_USE_WEAK=0 -static -pthread -std=c++0x -o thread thread.cc 
> $ ./thread 
> pthread_create works
> std::thread works
> ```
>
> However, if I change the code to call `std::thread::detach` instead of `join`, then it crashes again with `std::thread::detach` being resolved to zero.
>
> ```
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
> (gdb) bt
> #0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
> #1  0x0000000000439785 in std::thread::detach() ()
> #2  0x0000000000401f52 in main ()
> ```

В связи с этим на англоязычном StackOverflow [рекомендуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31271886/2553424) включить флаг компиляции `-Wl,--whole-archive`, либо [перечислить все необходимые библиотеки вручную, узнав предварительно список зависимостей через `nm`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27774767/2553424).

[А вообще](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7101577/2553424):

> Даже не думайте о статической компоновке. Разработчики glibc это не любят и не поддерживают. И однажды они начнут усложнять подобную практику с каждым релизом.
>
> ---
>
> *Do not even think about static linking. The glibc developers do not like it, they do not care about supporting it, and they somehow manage to break it a little harder with every release.*

Answer (score 2):

Как для любого динамического объекта - через `delete`. Только не забудьте сначала выполнить `th->join()` или `th->detach()`...

Comment: Если бы я выполнял join(), проблем бы не было. Поток, запустивший th, не должен прерыватся или ждать выполнения th.

Comment: @Gravit, а вам точно надо создавать объект в куче? Может просто создать его в стэке и выполнить detach?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, попробывал сделать с стеком, получаю ошибку сегментирования

Comment: @Gravit, уточню: на стеке потока надо создавать *данные* этого потока. А так, если у вас ошибка сегментации, значит, вы некорректно с этими данными работаете (и перенос их в кучу попросту маскирует проблему). Вы никуда не передаёте указатели на локальные переменные лямбды? Приведите, пожалуйста, минимальный код, при котором воспроизводится падение.

Comment: *Поток, запустивший th, не должен прерыватся или ждать выполнения th.* - т.е. он больше не взаимодействует с `th`? Ну так вызывайте `detach()` и удаляйте указатель. А еще лучше - делайте это с локальной переменной, ничего удалять не придется...

Comment: @Gravit, «получаю ошибку сегментирования» прочитайте, что Вам  yrHeTaTeJlb написал внимательнее. Особое внимание обратите на слово `detach`.

Comment: @Arhad @Harry @ixSci, https://pastebin.com/gcsHS9UY код для воспроизведения проблемы. Скомлировать так: `g++ test.cpp -lpthread -static`. Без ключа -static выполняется все корректно. Крашит на вызове detach()

Comment: Вы захватываете локальную переменную по референсу. Поскольку это указатель на глобальную переменную - захватывайте ее по значению. Иначе переменая может выйти из области действия раньше, чем начнется поток.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky падает даже при полном отсутствии кода внутри лямбды. Видимо я недостаточно точно написал действия в моей программе. Правильней было написать https://pastebin.com/Qphgp8g1

Comment: @Harry, вообще, надо менять заголовок вопроса на «Статически скомпонованная программа падает при std::thread::detach», но есть проблема — уточнения пришли после вашего ответа. Ответ тоже удалить не получится — в комментариях к нему достаточно важная информация. [Поднял дискуссию в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40410139#40410139).

Comment: @Arhad Ну извиняйте, кто ж знал :(